# React Typescript: Use a react hook on each item in an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm struggling on using a hook on each item on an array within my React Typescript project.

Without considering the limitations on using hooks, the code would be the following:

```
const forwardContractArray = useGetForwardArray()

interface ForwardResult {
        token: string;
        amount: number;
        expiryTime: number;
    }

const forwardResultArray: Array<ForwardResult> = []

for (let forwardAddress of forwardContractArray) {
  const { token, amount, expiryTime} = useForwardInfo(forwardAddress)
  forwardResultArray.push({token, amount, expiryTime})
}
```

Because of the limitations on running hooks in a for loop this is not possible to use a for loop for this.

Please could someone direct me on how to implement such a function within the scopes of React?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide please a minimal verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or codesandbox link or repo link so we can help knowing what are you exactly trying to achieve. Thank you

Comment: Either your `useForwardInfo` should be returning an array, or you should be rendering a unique component for each usage of `useForwardInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is first and foremost a UI library - so, if you want to show something for each element of an array, then you can have a component per item and inside the component you can use a single hook

```
return (
  <>
    { forwardContractArray
        .map(item => <ItemDisplay key={item.token} item={item} />) }
  </>
)
```

and then e.g.

```
function ItemDisplay({ item } : { item: ForwardResult }) {
  const { token, amount, expiryTime} = useForwardInfo(item);
  return (
    <p>Whatever you want to show for this item</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works!

For my useGetForwardArray() hook how do I stop this rendering every second? Preferably would only like this to render when the forward array is updated!

Comment: From your code it can't be seen why it should render every second - react learns about changes through e.g. useState hook or similar - check where and how you use it.